# list find and replace with elements in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do a find and replace on a `zip list`, using another list, but for some reason, I cannot seem to get my head around this rather `easy` problem. So, to start with, I have a zip list, which looks like (say `myzip_list`):

```
("this is a united string divided here","this is the value of the string),("this is a multiply string2 united here","this is the value of the string2)....
```

now, I have another list, which looks like so (say `replace_list`):

```
[['united', '##sharp'], ['divided', '##blunt'], ['multiply', '##med']]
```

What I'd like to do is replace the `myzip_list` [0] elements with the `double hash` value from `replace_list`. So, as an end result, I'd like to end up with:

```
myzip_list = ("this is a ##sharp string ##blunt here","this is the value of the string),("this is a ##med string2 ##sharp here","this is the value of the string2)....
```

Would appreciate if someone could maybe point me in the right direction...

*EDIT*

Cyber's answer below actually works if the `replace_list` consists of just one word. So, for example if `replace_list` looks like:

```
[['united all', '##sharp'], ['divided me', '##blunt'], ['multiply all', '##med']]
```

and if `myzip_list` looks like:

```
("this is a united all string divided me here","this is the value of the string),("this is a multiply all string2 united all here","this is the value of the string2)....
```

.. then Cybers approach fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['united', '##sharp'], ['divided', '##blunt'], ['multiply', '##med']]
d = dict(l)

>>> d
{'multiply': '##med', 'divided': '##blunt', 'united': '##sharp'}

tups = [("this is a united string divided here","this is the value of the string"),("this is a multiply string2 united here","this is the value of the string2")]

[[' '.join([d.get(i,i) for i in sub.split()]) for sub in tup] for tup in tups]
```

Output

```
[['this is a ##sharp string ##blunt here', 'this is the value of the string'],
 ['this is a ##med string2 ##sharp here', 'this is the value of the string2']]
```

Comment: the problem is that my `s` is actually a `zip list`. When I implement your solution I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Oh okay I see the issue. Edited my post.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cyber - it works perfectly and I like it since it is essentially a one liner :) Accepted your answer. Thanks again - saved me tonnes of time.

Comment: I seem to be having a small problem :(. So, your solution seems to work when `l` looks something like: `l = [['united', '##sharp'], ['divided', '##blunt'], ['multiply', '##med']]` but when `l` looks something like: `l = [['united all', '##sharp'], ['divided me', '##blunt'], ['multiply all', '##med']]`. So, it does not when when there are say 2 words :( - Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `zip`  function is its own inverse so if you have `zip` list unzip it with itself ! by a command like `zip(*your_list)` then use the below code !

```
import re
myzip_list="(this is a united string divided here,this is the value of the string),(this is a multiply string2 united here,this is the value of the string2)"
tempword=[w for w in re.split('\W', myzip_list) if w]
replace_list=[['united', '##sharp'], ['divided', '##blunt'], ['multiply', '##med']]
my_dict=dict(replace_list)
lst=my_dict.keys()

for i in range(len(tempword)) :
 for j in lst:
   if tempword[i]==j:
       tempword[i]=my_dict[j]

print ' '.join(tempword)
```

DEMO:

```
"this is a ##sharp string ##blunt here this is the value of the string this is a ##med string2 ##sharp here this is the value of the string2"
```

if you dont want to use `re` so  change `re.split('\W', myzip_list)` with `my_ziplist.split()` and remove `impoer re`.

Comment: no problem so do change `re.split('\W', myzip_list)` with `my_ziplist.split()` and remove `impoer re`. # i add this explain in edit !